# backbone.js - how and when to show a spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Is there any sort of hooks in backbone where I can easily say "whenever any of the collections is fetching data, show the spinner, hide it when they're done"?

I have a feeling it will be more complicated than that and require overwriting specific functions. When should I show the spinner? On `fetch()` or `refresh()` or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Backbone doesn't trigger any event when `Collection::fetch()` starts ([see source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-61)), so you will have to override the `fetch` method. Maybe something like this:

```
var oldCollectionFetch = Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch;

Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch = function(options) {
    this.trigger("fetch:started");
    oldCollectionFetch.call(this, options);
}
```

This will override the `fetch` method to give you an event when the fetch starts. However, this only triggers the event on the specific collection instance so if you have a bunch of different collections you'll have to listen for that event on each collection.

Comment: If you read through the rest of the source, you'll notice that the fetch calls sync, which then uses $.ajax. You don't need to listen to a backbone event to attach a spinner, you just need to watch for an ajax call. jQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop do just that.  http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-109

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about $.ajaxStart/Stop. That would be nice to use for a network activity indicator.

Comment: Nah @ryanmarc there are definitely advantages to using an event.  I wrote a post on this, http://tbranyen.com/post/how-to-indicate-backbone-fetch-progress ... also make sure you return the original fetch call otherwise the original return value is lost.

Comment: Do you really want to trigger it on every AJAX call, what if it's simply an automatic AJAX call to see if there are any new notifications (i.e. Inbox Counter, News Feed Counter).

Comment: What is with the request, sync and error events?
http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog - they seem to be exactly for this?

Answer (score 36):

You can use jQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop. Those will globally run when an ajax request is made, so fetch and save will cause those to run. Add your code to show the spinner in the start and hide it in the end.

Comment: This only handles one call at a time isn't it? So if I want to watch several requests in parallel, I'm out of luck.

Comment: You could have an AJAX counter to count the number of requests in progress, start with 0, increment it when ajaxStart and decrement it when ajaxStop. But do you really want to trigger it on every AJAX call, what if it's simply an automatic AJAX call to see if there are any new notifications (i.e. Inbox Counter, News Feed Counter).

Comment: jQuery already tracks the current number of running ajax requests. You don't need to keep track of this manually.

Comment: This idea doesn't work if the page makes other unrelated ajax calls.

Answer (score 25):

in Backbone.js 1.0.0 you can use the `request` and `sync` events http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog 
This goes in the view.

```
    initialize: function(){
        this.items = new APP.Collections.itemCollection();
        this.items.bind('request', this.ajaxStart, this);
        this.items.bind('sync', this.ajaxComplete, this);
    }

    ajaxStart: function(arg1,arg2,arg3){
        //start spinner
        $('#item-loading').fadeIn({duration:100});
    },
    ajaxComplete: function(){
        $('#item-loading').fadeOut({duration:100});
    }
```

This can be applied per collection or per model here's some CSS for the spinner http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-loading-spinner-for-backbonejs

Answer (score 8):

The way i have done this without overriding backbone is:

In view

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize; function(){

    this.$el.addClass('loading');
    collection.fetch(success:function(){
      this.$el.removeClass('loading')
    })
  }
})
```

The other route would be to remove the loading class when the models are added, usually you have:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize; function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'addAll')
    collection.bind('reset', this.addAll)

    this.$el.addClass('loading');
    collection.fetch();
  },
  addAll: function(){
    this.$el.removeClass('loading');
    collection.each(this.addOne);
  }
})
```

These would be almost identical in most cases, and as the loader is really for the users experience removing it just prior to displaying the content makes sense.

Comment: Just a note - collection.fetch(success, error) are just shortcuts to the jquery ajax method.

Comment: how'd you handle 'cancel' button to be shown to cancel loading ?

Answer (score 3):

And a little update. Since Dec. 13, 2012 have been added a `"request"` event to Backbone.sync, which triggers whenever a request begins to be made to the server. As well since Jan. 30, 2012 have been added a `"sync"` event, which triggers whenever a model's state has been successfully synced with the server (create, save, destroy).

So, you don't need to override or extand the native Backbone's methodes. For listening 'start/finish fetching' event you can add listener to your model/collection like this for example:

```
var view = new Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'request', this.yourCallback); //start fetching
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.yourCallback); //finish fetching
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method called `sync` on any of your models, and backbone.js will call that in order to sync.  Or you can simply replace the method `Backbone.sync.`  This will allow you to make the change in only one place in your source code.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [NProgress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) in my backbone and it is the best functioning loader/spinner out there.

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
     initialize: function () {
          this.items = new APP.Collections.itemCollection();
          this.items.on('reset', this.myAddFunction, this);
          NProgress.start();
          collection.fetch({
               reset:true,
               success: function () {
                   NProgress.done(true);
               }
          });
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Backbone sync method,
It will call every time backbone sync method, not only fetch, save, update and delete also

/* over riding of sync application every request come hear except direct ajax */

```
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync;
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    // Clone the all options
    var params = _.clone(options);

params.success = function(model) {
    // Write code to hide the loading symbol
     //$("#loading").hide();
    if (options.success)
        options.success(model);
};
params.failure = function(model) {
    // Write code to hide the loading symbol
     //$("#loading").hide();
    if (options.failure)
        options.failure(model);
};
params.error = function(xhr, errText) {
    // Write code to hide the loading symbol
     //$("#loading").hide();
    if (options.error)
        options.error(xhr, errText);
};
// Write code to show the loading symbol
     //$("#loading").show();
Backbone._sync(method, model, params);
};
```